# How can I disable VSCode's suggestions for language keywords?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently, Visual Studio Code offers helpful hints on common language keywords like `for` and `class` and `enum` (I'm using Typescript). I don't need assistance with these words - they're just noise, blocking me from seeing more relevant entries.

Is there a way I can disable suggestions for 'language keywords' only, but leave all the rest?

Comment: related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/45039

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using version `1.51.1` and i have perfectly disabled the keyword suggestion by adding these lines in `settings.json`

```
"editor.suggest.showKeywords": false,
```

Answer (score 2):

No, as of VS Code 1.21 you cannot filter out just the keyword suggestions in TypeScript and JavaScript.

Please [file a feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new) if you'd like to see this supported

Comment: Thanks for the link up!

Comment: You can prioritise snippets over keywords using this setting: `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"`. More about this here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_snippets-in-suggestions

Comment: Not sure this is valid anymore. See Mehbub's answer with: `"editor.suggest.showKeywords": false,`

Answer (score 2):

Please note that you now need to use:

```
"[typescript]": {
  "editor.suggest.showKeywords": false
}
```

which deprecates:

```
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.suggest.filteredTypes": {
        "keyword": false
    }
}
```