# Filtered intellisense in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I usually code with Visual Studio 2017, but when I program in Java or python I use Visual Studio Code.

In Visual Studio 2017 the intellisense have filters that allow you to see only the parameters, methods, snippets... making the job alot easier.

[image]

Visual Studio Code has intellisense but no filters, is there a way to activate them? or haven't been implemented yet?

[image]

Comment: Hi, as far as I know, there is no such feature in VS code, please check this doc: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense and we can request this feature in here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Afeature-request+sort%3Areactions-%2B1-desc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable VSCode's suggestions for language keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105475/how-can-i-disable-vscodes-suggestions-for-language-keywords)

Answer (score 0):

There's currently an issue for this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/50291

That said, you can remove [categories](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions) across the board in settings.json:

```
    "editor.suggest.filteredTypes": {
        "class": false
    },
```

(I'm filtering `class` because my React code was getting completion suggestions from *lots* of auto-generated CSS classes)