# Disable intrinsic suggestions on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Scenario:

If I write some statement of my preferred language and then I use <kbd>Tab</kbd> on Sublime Text 3 it puts basic structure of that sentence to use quickly.

[image: if completition on ST3]

But, if I try the same behavior on VSCode, it only completes the phrase instead of structure for that sentence, forcing me to:

1. Write the complete structure.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> and then use the arrows keys to choose some suggestion structure.
3. Use arrow keys before <kbd>Tab</kbd> to choose the suggestion I want.

Those three are slower than only write some statement and <kbd>Tab</kbd>…

TL;TR:

I want to disable the first line of suggestion to use structure suggestions for quickly development:

[image: if autocomplete]
[image: foreach autocomplete]

Are there some kind of `config.suggestionBuiltIn: false`? I have not seen some similar on the oficial documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable VSCode's suggestions for language keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105475/how-can-i-disable-vscodes-suggestions-for-language-keywords)

Comment: The first line is a keyword, the rest are snippets, as indicated by the icons.

Comment: @Gama11 exactly, I want to use some kind of shortcut (like tab) that helps me use snippets instead of suggested word.

Comment: You said you want to _disable_ the first suggestion - the linked question has an answer that does exactly that.

Comment: Also `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"` will help.

Comment: @Mark could you add your comment as an answer and explain it? it resolves my question, but I need to choose one answer to mark it as solved.

Comment: Probably better that you delete the question - no offense.  It would have to be edited to make clear what you intended that made my answer correct.  And then the question would be a duplicate so I shouldn't accept credit.  No worries.