# Cannot disable language "keyword" suggestions in VSCode with "editor.suggest.showKeywords": false

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been trying to disable the keyword popup in VSCode, but the suggested method of adding "editor.suggests.showKeywords": false, doesn't work, as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105475/how-can-i-disable-vscodes-suggestions-for-language-keywords).

This is how it looks in my settings.json file, along with some other attempts that also haven't worked, commented out.

[image: vscode_screenshot]

Any ideas on how to disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. I had the Pylance extension installed. By setting the `languageServer` to `jedi`, and switching to the following, I fixed the issue:

```
"Pylance": "python.languageServer": "Pylance"
```